# HTML5 + LLVM = Win? Or not existent?

Tags: html, browser, llvm, multimedia

I tried a simple breakout clone in a browser and saw it take 25% of my CPU. Sad.

I was wondering if LLVM can hook into HTML5 and take advantage of canvas, SVG and etc.
If not does LLVM have its own multimedia layer? I ran my version of chrome with --enable-nacl and it looks like it is enabled (half of the native client demos ran http://naclports.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/gallery/index.html). Since chrome supports it now is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are you talking about LLVM as in Low-Level Virtual Machine ?

Comment: Then I think you might misinterpret what LLVM is. It does not provide any highlevel layers such as graphics, let alone a HTML5 renderer. The "Low-Level" in their name is to be taken literally :-) See the features page: http://llvm.org/Features.html

Comment: @DarkDust: Maybe you misunderstood as well. I want to use LLVM to execute the code and somehow have it hook into HTML5. If you look at [this page](http://naclports.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/gallery/index.html) you can see some demos draw to screen and running LLVM code

Comment: it's possible, as it could be possible to integrate a JavaScript engine etc... however I am not aware of any such project yet.

Answer (score 4):

LLVM does not provide any such feature itself.

But you might be interested in the [Emscripten](http://code.google.com/p/emscripten/) project, which is a compiler from LLVM IR to JavaScript. The author has taken ray tracers and other programs written in C++, and compiled them to run in the browser automatically. It's very cool!